# Unable to deploy/move forward with simple web app

Tags: php, mysql, git, heroku

Beginning details:

1. Windows 7 Professional 64 bit
2. WAMP Version: 2.5
3. MySQL Version: 5.6.17
4. PHP Version: 5.5.12
5. Apache Version: 2.4.9

I also have Git, Heroku Toolbelt, etc.

---

I'm trying to deploy a PHP inventory web app I have on my computer using Heroku.

Currently, it's installed on my PC using WAMP server. Up to this point, it was just a web app used at a country club where any computer/phone/tablet could access and adjust inventory as long as they were on the same wireless network as the server.

Right now, I'm trying to get to the point where the country club can access the app from anywhere, and figured, I could host it on Heroku.

Every tutorial I watch/read explains how to deploy a single index.php file that contains a single line of code saying something like, `"Hello world!"`, but this app contains 8 folders and 22 PHP files, all in the "www" file of WAMP. I've tried learning the concepts of how this works (creating a single file for everything; trying to deploy the index.php I already have, etc.)

I have tried tutorials and a lot of Heroku reading and attempts, but I'm unable to move forward with anything in terms of adding user authentication or the ability to sell it to restaurants/country clubs. I've combed through every word on Heroku tutorials, and I don't run into a single error during anything I try, but at the end of it all, when I try "heroku open", it opens up a blank page.

My "www" directory contains:
- cgi-bin 
- css 
- dbBackup 
- img 
- inc 
- js 
- tcpdf
- tmp

Then, there are all the PHP files of the different functions of the app listed below those.

My main question here is...what is the file that gets deployed on Heroku in this situation? I don't understand how the CSS, JS, and other database-related functions are included in a single index.php file that is apparently the file that's deployed when you launch a web app like this.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Just most of the replies I ever see on forums are that enough details aren't given.

"I've got an inventory web app written in PHP that consists of several files and folders. I want to host it on Heroku. Every single tutorial or instruction explains how to deploy a single file. How do I deploy a complete and functioning web app that contains several files and folders?"

Comment: I am trying to prune it down k?

Comment: Out of curiosity what drove you to Heroku, and why didn't the developer help out on a strawman POC deployment in the cloud?

Comment: Heroku seemed to be the simplest of all, and this app won't get much traffic from the club considering it would only be them using it, so nothing big was needed.

The developer disappeared on me. Everything was done from scratch and every little thing was completely custom. But then he vanished and nobody has been able to help me. I've hired 5 or 6 different people on Elance, and nobody understands the development of the app, despite the fact that it's completely functioning with no bugs. 

As far as the cloud, the club didn't want that initially. The simplicity and time saved changed that...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I don't know much about Heroku, but could easily do it there or elsewhere for no charge

Comment: Would love to connect with you then. Send me a message a we'll go forward. vint.inventory@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The default page loaded when a site is accessed is typically "index.html" or "index.htm". This file would normally have the content to create the initial splash page with links to the different services you might offer. Those services are what you would use php for with the supporting data in your MySQL database. In addition to copying your base files and directories over to the Heroku server, you will also need to create the MySQL tables and then populate them with data. This is a relatively simple process using the MySQL Workbench. It may be tedious if you have lots of tables and schema, but it is relatively simple. Comment back if you need help in this area or would like to discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku runs a standard web server and looks for "index.php" as your starting file by default. You should have either an "index.htm", "index.html", or "index.php" file in your current base (www) directory. If you don't then it's likely that you currently start your app by going to a URL (www.yourwebsite.com) followed by a slash and some other text, such as "/tcpdf/startup.html". 

 If you have one of the index. files, then that's your starting point. Copy the complete set of files and directories over to your heroku site and then test it based on the URL they have given you, which will automatically look for an 'index.php' file. You will need to back up and restore your database from your local system to the heroku server, which is relatively straightforward using the mysql workbench. You'll need to recreate the users and their schema permissions on the heroku site so that the php files can access the new database.